# Loading images from asset folder or drawable?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-resources

I am using a mapview with Google Maps and adding markers to the map using following code:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
 .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(getResources().getIdentifier(iconFileName, "drawable", this.getActivity().getPackageName()))));
```

Is there a more resource-friendly way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this code??

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentpos)
            .title("Marker")
            .snippet("My marker.")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mark_start)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply load marker from `drawable` folder as follows...

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.icon_file_name));
```

Comment: Does it use less resources?

Comment: It's actually the same. And NO there's no way to use less resources.

Comment: No, it doesn't use less resource...there's no way to use less resource when you are loading your resources from the resource folder. But, my suggestion will reduce code complexity to load markers icon.